# Flatlist not re-rendering when data is removed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

My react-native flatlist isn't re-rendering when data is removed from the `sortedData` prop to the flatlist. I tried using the `extraData` prop to force a re-render, but that didn't work. When I remove the elements, blank rows appear.

```
handleRemove = (title) => {
    // const start = this.state.people.slice(0, index);
    // const end = this.state.people.slice(index + 1);
    // this.setState({
    //   people: start.concat(end),
    // });
    const filteredData = this.state.sortedData.filter(
      (item) => item.title !== title
    );
    this.setState({ sortedData: filteredData });
  };

  render() {
    const { sortedData } = this.state;

    return (
      <FlatList
        data={sortedData}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <LeaderboardEntry
            song={item}
            handler={this.handler}
            onRemove={() => this.handleRemove(item.title)}
          />
        )}
      />
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do like below

```
 var newSortedData = [...this.state.sortedData];
    newSortedData.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({
      sortedData: newSortedData,
    });
```

The reason is even though you are updating the state its pointed to the same array in state so you need to use the spread operator which would create a new array which in turn would cause a re render.

**Update**
Using filter to remove items
Your flat list should be changed to

```
onRemove={() => this.handleRemove(item.title,index)}
```

Logic for the handle remove function

```
handleRemove = (title,index) => {
    const filteredData = this.state.sortedData.filter(
      (item,index) => item.index !== in
    );
    this.setState({ sortedData: filteredData });
  };
```

Here the title parameter is not required at all, you can remove it as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately it's deleting two items at a time. Any idea why?

Comment: may i know which two items ? like is it next to the index you chose ?

Comment: Did you do any code changes ? because splice will remove 1 item starting in the index you provide so this should work

Comment: I'll update the code to the new codebase. The error we're having now, is that when the data array for the flatlist is passed in, multiple items are deleted.

Comment: This is a totally different question, the problem you have is the filter logic, earlier you were removing based on index not based on the title you pass, if two or more items are having the same title they will be removed you will have to pass something like the id of the item and remove based on that